# Unit Tests run when installing unmanaged package?

Tags: unit-test, unmanaged-package

When installing an unmanaged package will the unit tests run?  We're working with a partner that installed a package (I can see it in Setup | Installed Packages).  The package has no namespace prefix so I assume it's an unmanaged package.  After installation we experienced UT failures trying to deploy code so I want to see others' experiences.  Since the partner successfully did the install and didn't raise any issues (they wouldn't know how to fix our UTs) I have to assume the UTs didn't run.

I did have UTs fail installing a managed package myself so I know UTs run for managed packages but that doesn't seem to be the case with an unmanaged package?

Comment: Managed UT do not seem to run while using the UI to install (but they do if you use the Migration Toolkit). If it did, it'd often take much longer than the 10-20 seconds needed to install a typical app. Especially in our org, which has over 300 unit tests, and any unit test using an account would take at least 8 seconds per account, because of our massive triggers.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  When I installed Marketo it ran UTs - but it said it'd take a while & would email me when installation was finished.  So, I assume that means it used the Migration Toolkit.

Comment: Not necessarily. The "we'll email you when done" doesn't include UTs. It simply means that the install queue is backed up. It does take a finite amount of time to create the metadata, so larger packages are processed in a queue.

Comment: Only reason I know UTs ran is because they failed. Took a while to figure out Marketo used API v30 whereas my UTs ran with v24. Confusing thing is SF kept reporting 'install successful' but the objects weren't installed. I checked debug logs and realized what happened...